# React Native navigation.navigate route parameters are correct but data is not updating

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

React Native `navigation.navigate` route parameters are correct but data is not updating.
While refreshing the page, the API works and everything looks fine.

```
const PollQuestions = ( {navigation,route} ) => {

  const {userInfo} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const userid = userInfo.USERID; //userid

  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([]);
  const { part_id } = route.params; //survey_id
  const { part_name } = route.params; // survey_name
  const { qid } = route.params; // qid

  //api not refreshing//
  const [questiondata, setQuestionData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://.....&qid=${qid}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setQuestionData(json))
  }, []); 
  //!!!this api works fine but when navigating with navigation.navigate route params, it shows old data!!!//

return (
  ....
 )
```

Comment: how are you refreshing the page?

Comment: I have survey questions, for example, I am recording the 1st question. Then I want the 2nd question to be opened.

I trigger API by sending parameters with navigation.navigate by making this action an intermediate page